# Makefile wildcard (static rule?) with phony

Tags: makefile, target

I'm just starting to really grok the inner workings of make. Yet I do not understand why the following doesn't work:

```
test%: test%.foo
     @echo $@
     @echo $<

all: test1 test2

.PHONY: all test1 test2
```

Expected behavior:

```
$ make
test1
test1.foo
test2
test2.foo
# 1,2 Order not important
```

However, I get:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

("make all", "make test1", etc make no difference).

Can someone explain why the PHONY test rules aren't being executed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excerpt from the GNU make manual.

> Since it knows that phony targets do not name actual files that could
>   be remade from other files, make skips the implicit rule search for
>   phony targets (see section Using Implicit Rules). This is why
>   declaring a target phony is good for performance, even if you are not
>   worried about the actual file existing.

This means that as your `test1` and `test2` targets are phony, make does not search for implicit rules for them. Even if what you use is more accurately named *pattern rules*, all pattern rules are implicit rules.

Comment: Ah, it's that last bit "all pattern rules are implicit rules" that's new to me.  Is canonical-ish way to force make to do what I want in this instance?

Comment: Make `test1` and `test2` non-phony, e.g. by adding `@touch $@`.

Comment: @reinierpost: It won't change anything to have actual `test1` and `test2` files. They are defined in the Makefile as phony, so they are phony, regardless of existing files. To make them non-phony, the only way is to remove them from the `.PHONY` rule.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: Thanks for the correction.  I meant to say that once they're non-phony, it's a good idea to actually create them.

Comment: @reinierpost: No! It's the opposite: files should never exist. - Once the targets are non phony, if they exist, their timestamp will be compared to the dependents timestamps. And if the targets are more recent, no build will be made. This is not what is expected for a phony (but not declared as such) target!

Comment: But it *is* what is expected for a non-phony target.

Comment: @Pat to force it to do what you want, you can `FORCE` it! :-) https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html